# How can I do nested includes with a pure (reentrant) flex/bison parser?

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I've been flipping my parser/lexer over to a reentrant implementation, and the final hurdle is the ability to do nested `include script.txt` type instructions.

This is what I've implemented for the `include` bit: *but it seg-faults*, otherwise the rest of the tokenizer and parser works fine:

```
^{include}{ws}+     { BEGIN INCL;             }
<INCL>[^ \t\n\r\f]+ { /* Swallow everything up to whitespace or an EOL character.
                       * When state returns to initial, the whitepsace
                       * and/or EOL will be taken care of. */
                      {
                        FILE * _yyin;
                        _yyin = fopen ( yytext, "r" );
                        if (! _yyin) {
                          char buf[256];
                          snprintf(buf, DIM(buf) - 1,"Script include file ""%s"" couldn't be opened: %s.",yytext,strerror(errno));
                          yyerror(yyscanner, "buf");
                        } else {
                          extern int yyparse( yyscan_t * scanner);
                          yyscan_t incl_scanner;
                          struct my_parser_data incl_data;

                          yylex_init(& incl_scanner);
                          yylex_init_extra(& incl_data, & incl_scanner);
                          yyset_in( _yyin, & incl_scanner);

                          /* This call causes a segmentation fault. */
                          yyparse(& incl_scanner);

                          yylex_destroy( & incl_scanner);
                        }
                      }
                      BEGIN 0;
                    }
```

***How would I go about implementing the nested includes?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't call *both* `yylex_init` and `yylex_init_extra`. You call one or the other; if you need extra data, you call `yylex_init_extra` *instead of* `yylex_init`.

However, that is not what is producing the segfault. The double call to `yylex_init` is a memory leak, not a segfault.

The segfault comes from passing the *address of* `incl_scanner` to `yyset_in`, `yyparse` and `yylex_destroy`. Those functions expect the *value of* the `scanner_t` argument (which is a pointer).

Here's a relevant example from the [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Extra-Data.html):

```
         yylex_init_extra( buf, &scanner );
         yyset_in( in, scanner );
         yylex( scanner );
         yylex_destroy( scanner );
```

Note which functions take `&scanner` and which just take `scanner`.